# For Loop to get Data from custom ArrayList

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am just trying to get `state name` using `state id`, for an example: my **strId** is **1**, but not getting *state name* which belongs to *strId 1*, everytime getting **last state name** found in `stateModelArrayList`

```
for (int i=0; i<stateModelArrayList.size(); i++) {
    String strId = stateModelArrayList.get(i).getId().toString();
    if(strId.equals(strState)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, strId+" : "+strState, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        strStateName = stateModelArrayList.get(strId).getName().toString();         
    }
        editState.setText(strStateName);
}
```

Comment: Try Loging your strId inside your loop,and make sure that your condition mets.

Comment: condition mets perfectly... as you can I am using Toast to show strId if equals to strState... and getting exact result, I supposed to get

Comment: ```strStateName = stateModelArrayList.get(strId).getName().toString();``` this is weird, why are you passing ```strId``` to ```get``` and not ```i```?

Comment: Yes, Jorn Vernee is correct.

Comment: thank you your solution worked for me @JornVernee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your mistake is here:

```
strStateName = stateModelArrayList.get(strId).getName().toString();
```

It should be:

```
strStateName = stateModelArrayList.get(i).getName().toString();
```

If you don't want to get the last value don't forget to call `break` to stop the loop